# Flexslider not working

Tags: javascript

This is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(window).load(function() {  
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({  
            animation: "fade"  
       });  
       $().UItoTop({ easingType: 'easeOutQuart' });  
   });    
 </script>
```

Comment: please mention what error u face it

Comment: Yes, please tell us the error. And maybe post your html? Are you importing jQuery and the flexslider css and js files?

Comment: Also, have you tried running it without the UItoTop plugin to make sure the problem is with flexslider and not with UItoTop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything works fine for me, please check to have included all the necessary resources, in my example are:

1. obviously jQuery (1.9.1 but I tried older and newer version too)
2. relevant scripts and css
3. existence of the images used by the slider

Scripts:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/js/jquery.easing.js"></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://lab.mattvarone.com/projects/jquery/totop/js/jquery.ui.totop.js"></script>
```

Css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/css/flexslider.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://lab.mattvarone.com/projects/jquery/totop/css/ui.totop.css">
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/cusuy/